# PHP Directories

Tags: php, directory

Can someone please xplain this code. Im reading larry ullmans book on php and i dont get this part. Thanks in advance!!

```
$search_dir = '.';
$contents = scandir($search_dir);

    print '<h2>Directories</h2>
    <ul>';
    foreach ($contents as $item) {
    if ( (is_dir($search_dir . '/' . $item)) AND (substr($item, 0, 1) != '.') ) {
    print "<li>$item</li>\n";
    }
    }
print '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll repost your code with comments to exaplain what each line does.

```
$search_dir = '.'; //Set the directory to search. "." means the current one.
$contents = scandir($search_dir); //scan the directory and return its results into $contents

print '<h2>Directories</h2>
    <ul>';
foreach($contents as $item) { //Iterate through the array and for each item...
    //If the item is a directory        AND it doesn't start with a . (which means the current one)...
    if ((is_dir($search_dir.'/'.$item)) AND(substr($item, 0, 1) != '.')) {
        print "<li>$item</li>\n"; //Print it
    }
}
print '</ul>';
```

In short, it prints out an output of the directories inside the directory the script is running in.

Comment: thank you! i have one question though. If i take the $search_dir.'/'. away the same result comes up. why is that needed?

Comment: That's because if your $search_dir is different then `.` (you want to get the directories in a different directory), you'd fail, because it'll look for `is_dir($item)` (on the same directory as the script). By coincidence, the search dir and the current dir are the same.

Comment: im sorry to be a pain but how would the array of the $contents look like and how would the $item look like?

Comment: From the [Manual](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php): "Returns an array of files and directories from the *directory*." See the examples in that article to understand how the array looks like

Comment: thank you! :) i dont understand the dots and why they show up... Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => bar.php
    [3] => foo.txt
    [4] => somedir
)

Answer (score 1):

It shows you list of all directories in current directory